# How are keys locked in KV Stores?

Tags: database, go, concurrency, key-value-store

I am building a distributed KV store just to learn a little bit more about distributed systems and concurrency. The implementation of the KV store I am building is completely transactional, with an in-memory transaction log. The storage is also completely in-memory just for simplicity. The API exposes the `GET`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REMOVE`. Note that all endpoints operate on a single key, not a range of keys.

I am managing concurrency via locks. However, I have a single global lock that locks the entire datastore. This sound terribly inefficient because if I want to read the value for `K1` while I update `K2`, I must wait for k2 to finish updating despite being unrelated.

I know that there are DBs that use more granular locking. For example, in MySQL servers there are row-level locks. How can key-level locks be implemented?

I have

```
type Storage struct {
  store map[string]int32
}
```

Should I add something like this?:

```
type Storage struct {
  store map[string]int32
  locks map[string]mutex.Lock
}
```

The issue if I do this is that `locks` has to be kept in sync with the `store`. Another option would be to combine the two maps, but even then I come into the issue of deleting an entry in the map **while the lock is being held** if a `REMOVE` request comes before a `GET`.

Comment: Suggestion: consider [Readers-writers locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock): allow multiple concurrent readers; restrict only for "writes".

Comment: Thats a great suggestion. However, it does not fix the problem with deleting of a key. What will happen when the key is deleted? How will the mutex be deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to lock the "key" - you can lock the *operation* (e.g. "add key", "read key", "delete key").  For that matter,  I'm unclear why you believe you need "transactions" here.  There are a lot of details you haven't told us :(  STRONG SUGGESTION: [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: I have lots of questions, including a) your platform(s), b) your programming language(s), c) the extent to which you're able/willing to use 3rd party libraries/technologies (e.g. a msg queue) vs. DIY (for the "learning experience").  But these articles might be of interest:  [How to do distributed locking, Martin Kleppmann](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html), and  https://davidecerbo.medium.com/everything-i-know-about-distributed-locks-2bf54de2df71

Comment: If I lock just the operation then I can get stale reads. I do not need transactions, but I want to gurantee strong consitency, A transaction log is an easy way to achieve this, since I can just refer to it to get the latest state of the DB and assure that it is consitent accross replicas.

I guess that a transaction log may not be needed here though, and I can probably just store the data with a version and use that for consensus.

Comment: I think my main issue here was making the KV Store transactinoal, when its not needed (I can do versioning in the data layer). I can keep strong consitency without the log, just with versioning. Crazily enough, I asked ChatGPT and it cleared it up for me and I fact checked it. I will answer my own question below, but will not use what ChatGPT said since it goes against rules. I'll just answer what I understood.

Comment: Sorry, took me a long time to write the answer. But thank you a lot for the pointer on Readers-writers locks, it pointed me to sync.Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Concetual part

### Transactions

First, transaction logs are not needed for strong consitency. Transaction logs are useful for upholding ACID properties.

Transactions are also not strictly required for strong consistency in a database, but they can be a useful tool for ensuring consistency in many situations.

Strong consistency refers to the property that ensures that all reads of a database will return the most recent write, regardless of where the read operation is performed. In other words, strong consistency guarantees that all clients will see the same data, and that the data will be up-to-date and consistent across the entire system.

You can use a consensus algorithm, such as Paxos or Raft, to assure strong consistency. When storing data, you can store data with a version, and use that as the ID in Paxos.

### Locking in KV Stores

In a key-value (KV) store, keys are typically locked using some kind of locking mechanism, such as a mutex or a reader-writer lock (as suggested by @paulsm4). This allows multiple threads or processes to access and modify the data in the KV store concurrently, while still ensuring that the data remains consistent and correct.

For example, when a thread or process wants to read or modify a particular key in the KV store, it can acquire a lock for that key. This prevents other threads or processes from concurrently modifying the same key, which can lead to race conditions and other problems. Once the thread or process has finished reading or modifying the key, it can release the lock, allowing other threads or processes to access the key.

The specific details of how keys are locked in a KV store can vary depending on the implementation of the KV store. Some KV stores may use a global lock (as you were already doing, which is sometimes inefficient) that locks the entire data store, while others may use more granular locking mechanisms, such as row-level or key-level locks, to allow more concurrent access to the data.

So tldr; conceptually, you were right. The devil is in the details of the implementation of the locking.

## Coding

To strictly answer the question about locking, one can consider [Readers-writers locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) as suggested by @paulsm4. In golang, a similar lock is [`RWMutex`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.4:src/sync/rwmutex.go;l=36). It is used in [`sync.Map`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.4:src/sync/map.go;l=34).

Here is a short example:

```golang
type Storage struct {
  store sync.Map // a concurrent map
}

// GET retrieves the value for the given key.
func (s *Storage) GET(key string) (int32, error) {
  // Acquire a read lock for the key.
  v, ok := s.store.Load(key)
  if !ok {
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("key not found: %s", key)
  }

  // Return the value.
  return v.(int32), nil
}

// INSERT inserts the given key-value pair into the data store.
func (s *Storage) INSERT(key string, value int32) error {
  // Acquire a write lock for the key.
  s.store.Store(key, value)
  return nil
}

// UPDATE updates the value for the given key.
func (s *Storage) UPDATE(key string, value int32) error {
  // Acquire a write lock for the key.
  s.store.Store(key, value)
  return nil
}

// REMOVE removes the key-value pair for the given key from the data store.
func (s *Storage) REMOVE(key string) error {
  // Acquire a write lock for the key.
  s.store.Delete(key)
  return nil
}
```

You would need Paxos on top of this to ensure consistency accross replicas.